# RecyclerView scrolling not working with SwipeRefreshLayout in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm using a SwipeRefreshLayout with a RecyclerView, both in a Fragment.

The RecyclerView won't scroll down.

This is the Layout of my Main Activity:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       >
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
            <!-- Replaced with Fragment -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This works fine - the Fragment with the problematic RecyclerView replaces the LinearLayout with the ID fragment_placeholder which you can see above.

Fragment Layout is here:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/content_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The Swipe-Refresh-Gesture is working fine, but if the content of the RecyclerView exceeds the screensize, the scrolling won't work.

I've tried to set nestedScrollingEnabled(true) but it does not work either.

```
RecyclerView dataView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.content_recycler_view);
final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
dataView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
adapter = new ListContentAdapter();
dataView.setAdapter(adapter);
dataView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

It's only scrolling, if I wrap a NestedScrollView around the RecyclerView:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout">
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/content_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

But this destroys the advantage of the RecyclerView, reusing it's views.
Why it does not scroll?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes After adding Nestedscrollview it's worked for me.Thank You!!!

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/content_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/content_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```